# Hiding WordPress REST endpoints from public viewing using Basic Authentication

Tags: plugin-development, api, wp-api

I have this function which register new endpoint. By default the end point is public. I'm using Application Passwords'  plugin which create a basic authentication account, let's say `Basic 64basePassword`

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2', 'somthing', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'callback_function',
    ));

});
```

There is argument named `permission_callback`, but this use cookies. 
Can I use `permission_callback` or anything else to hiding the endpoint so only requests with basic authentication can access the endpoint?
Or let me ask: Using basic authentication in headers, let's say 'Authorization: Basic some64basePass'

How I can check the value of Authorization in the header is valid or not?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "basic aauthentication"?

Comment: @MarkKaplun please refer to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/

Comment: Also used by this plugin 'Application Passwords' https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/

Comment: I should not refer to anything :( questions should be self contained with no need to refer to external resources. Here the term "basic authentication" usually refers to htaccess setup, so if this is not what you mean you should edit the question and specify what you mean. Regardless if you are looking for integration with plugins than it is off topic unless you explain also how the integration supposed to be done.

Comment: @MarkKaplun basic authentication is standard in the HTTP protocol. It doesn't need me to explain it. you can found it mention in  WP REST API https://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/

Comment: so what prevents you from adding it in htacces?

Comment: .... once you got to wordpress level your http connection was already authenticated

Comment: I want to hiding wp REST endpoints, by default all custom endpoints are public.

Comment: last comment... what do you mean in "hide" and what does it have to do with basic authentication. I am sure I am not special, but I have a suspicion that if I do not understand what is it that you actually want, other might fail in that as well

Comment: @Yamona I think that you main problem is in the sentence "There is argument named permission_callback, but this use cookies". This is wrong, in this callback, you just need to return `TRUE` or `FALSE` but before this return you can use what you want to check if the user is allowed : basic authentication, testing arguments, ...

Comment: @mmm can you give me an example with testing what in the headers true or false? let's say "Authorization: something" for example.

Comment: read this https://secure.php.net/manual/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.
Inside the callback function I validate  `Authorization` from the header like this:

```
function callback_function($data) {
    //Get HTTP request headers 
    $auth = apache_request_headers();
    //Get only Authorization header
    $valid = $auth['Authorization'];

    // Validate
    if ($valid == 'Basic Base64UsernamePassword') {
        //Do what the function should do
    } else {
        $response = 'Please use a valid authentication';
    }

    return json_encode($response);
}
```